# Datasets are rendered out of order with typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead.js

I am using typeahead for search on 3 datasets. When I don't include a minLength, the datasets are rendered in the order that they are listed in my code; when i include a minLength for some of the datasets and not all, the order changes (see code below). The problem I have is that I want the user-list to always render appear first in the dropdown, the topic-list to always appear second, and the sec-list to always appear third.

```
$('#autocomplete').typeahead([
    {
      name: 'users-list',                                                        
      prefetch: {url: "/prefetch_users/", ttl:1},
      template: [                                                                 
        '<p class=""><a href={{url}}>{{name}}</a></p>',                              
        '<img class="userimg_small" src="{{img}}">'                         
      ].join(''),                                                                 
      engine: Hogan, 
      limit: 4,                                                          
      minLength: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'topic-list',                                                        
      prefetch: {url: "/prefetch_topics/", ttl:1},
      template: '<p class=""><a href={{url}}>{{value}}</a></p>',
      engine: Hogan,
      limit: 3,
      minLength: 3                                            
    },
    {
      name: 'sec-list',                                                        
      prefetch: {url: "/prefetch_secs/", ttl:1},
      remote: {url: "/remote_secs/?q=%QUERY", ttl:1, rateLimitWait: 150},
      template: '<p class=""><a href={{url}}>{{ticker}} - {{name}}</a></p>',
      engine: Hogan                                   
    }
]);
```

Comment: ... what is the query you are using (that is: what did you type in the  input text field?). Specifically: what length was it?

Comment: 3 letters, i pasted in the query: "col" as an example. so it is getting picked up by all three filters

Comment: Well, "col" doesn't get picked up by 'users-list', since its `minLength` is 4, and `"col".length === 3`. I am guessing this is why you don't see "users-list".

Comment: minLength on users-list is 2; limit is 4. this isn't a problem of getting picked up - this is about the order of the datasets being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so looking the code for `dropdown_view.js` in Typeahead, it appears that what you are describing is correct, and there's no way around it without changing code (at least none that comes to mind right now).

What happens is that whenever a dataset matches a query, the code will see if there ever were suggestions from the dataset. If so, it will simply update the suggestions for that dataset. Otherwise, it will create a new "dataset" section in the dropbox, and *append* that dataset to the dropdown, at the very bottom.

So the order in which you see them will not change after the first time (that is: 3 will always be before 1, if this ever was the case), and that order depends on which dataset first matches your query.

For you, that changes because of the different `minLength`'s.

I suppose you could fork and change the code -- it's a small change.

Otherwise, I suppose you could also write a very ugly hack to use internal functions, and render a one-time list of one dummy suggestion per each dataset.